# can not change the pivot of a sprite in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I want my character to have choice for haircut in my game so create many hair. But each has each shape (https://imgur.com/a/wcpFP4D) so I want to have a custom pivot for each sprite. I've already change sprite pivot in sprite editor (https://imgur.com/a/qGR0XMH). But when I drop the sprite into the scene editor, the pivot stay at the center (https://imgur.com/a/emGR1i3)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

click on the button it will give you 2 options center , pivot change it to pivot instead of center

if you don't have the option, in the scene view right click on the scene tab > overlays > tool settings